# How can i read multile csv files at once at python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation, statistics

```
df1 =  pd.read_table('CUSR0000SS62031.csv', sep=',')
df2 =  pd.read_table('CUUR0000SS62031.csv', sep=',')
df3 =  pd.read_table('CUSR0000SERA02.csv', sep=',')
df4 =  pd.read_table('CUUR0000SERA02.csv', sep=',')
df5 =  pd.read_table('CUUR0000SEFR02.csv', sep=',')
```

Now I am writing codes like this in order to load the csv files....but it takes time to produce codes...

If I have an array of the filenames, can I automate the above codes with a while/for loop? Thanks so much, I have tried but not sure how to also change the name of the df1 to n automatically...Thanks!!

Comment: If you really want to read them "at once", you'll want to look at the excellent `multiprocessing` library in python.  It's an advanced topic but a powerful one, which would enable you to run multiple processes concurrently to read the CSV files all at the same time, leveraging today's modern multi-core CPUs to get things don real quick.

Comment: Thank you so much! absolutely an eye opener for me!

Comment: @DanFarrell since disk I/O is the main bottleneck here, I'm not sure multiprocessing adds something here (but complexity). Well, it would need some benchmarking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating variable names is not a good idea, but as a nice alternative, you could create your dataframes in a list comprehension:

```
df_list = [pd.read_table(f,sep=',') for f in ['CUSR0000SS62031.csv','CUUR0000SS62031.csv','CUSR0000SERA02.csv','CUUR0000SERA02.csv','CUUR0000SEFR02.csv']]
```

then access your dataframes by index (ex: `df_list[1]`) or in a loop:

```
for dfx in df_list:
   # do something with dfx pd.dataframe object
```